# Functionalities of expression builder in Autofield plugin available in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis-3, autofields

Basically, what I try to do is automated calculation ***while editing*** (not with field calculator).

In QGIS 2.18 you could do automated calculations while editing with the Autofield Plugin. Since QGIS 3.X, you can do automated calculation of geometry (while editing) via the Properties > Standard values.

However, with the Autofield plugin you could also work with expressions based on existing field values. It seems that this is not possible in QGIS 3.4.: for some reason the fields and values don't show up in the expression window (Properties > Standard values), only *NULL* is available:
[image]

Does anybody know what I am missing, or if this functionality still exist in QGIS 3.4?